# Cross-browser attribute selection in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I don't have access to JQuery for whatever reason, I usually perform attribute selection manually using `element.hasAttribute` or `element.getAttribute`.

However, there seems to be some complication here because older browsers (IE <= 8) don't support `hasAttribute`.  So if you want to check whether an element has a certain attribute, you need to use `getAttribute` and check the return value.

```
if ((element.hasAttribute && element.hasAttribute("foo"))
    || (element.getAttribute("foo") != null))
{
  ....
}
```

This makes me think you may as well just forget about using `hasAttribute` at all, and just always use `getAttribute`.  The problem is that I can't find consistent documentation on the **return value** of `getAttribute`.  In practice, it returns `null` on most browsers if the attribute doesn't exist - but it also might return **[empty string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute#Notes)**, because that is what it's supposed to do according to the DOM 3 specification.

Unfortunately, returning an empty string leaves us with no way to disambiguate between:

```
<div data-my-attribute = ""></div>
```

and

```
<div></div>
```

So, in practice - it seems the most portable thing to do is to first check if the browser supports `hasAttribute`, and if not, use `getAttribute` - since IE 6-8 implement `getAttribute` so that it returns `null` (instead of empty string) if the attribute doesn't exist.

Is this really the best way to go about doing this?  Or is there a better way to write cross-browser attribute detection in plain Javascript?

Comment: Welcome to the main reason jQuery exists. Browser normalization isn't easy.

Comment: Look at some framework source code to get ideas.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to say the best idea is probably to avoid things like `data-*` attributes altogether, they usually do nothing more than break separation of concerns.  You might be interested on how jQuery actually does this though - http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.attr

Comment: Could you provide a use case where you'd really need to disambiguate between `<div foo="">` and `<div>`?

Comment: @thg435 according to the spec, the former is truthy, and the latter is falsy

Comment: I'm just thinking out lout, but maybe `<input ... required>` is such a case.

Comment: I don't know exactly what are the reasons you aren't using jQuery, but if the reason is its size, you could use Sizzle (http://sizzlejs.com/) that is the core part of jQuery extracted to another library, useful only for selecting elements, weighting only 4KB minified.

Answer (score 1):

The following works well in IE6-10 (tested it in IETester), Firefox, Chrome and Safari:

```js
function hasAttrib(element, attributeName) {
  return (typeof element.attributes[attributeName] != 'undefined');
}
```

Here are [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krTXh/) and its standalone [result page](http://jsfiddle.net/krTXh/show) (for testing in older browsers).

Answer (score 0):

This will probably need some testing, but would not the length of the *String* describing the *Element* change if you tried to *setAttribute* an attribute it doesn't already have vs remain the same if you tried for one it does have?

```
var hasAttribute = (function () {
    if (HTMLElement && HTMLElement.prototype
                    && HTMLElement.prototype.hasAttribute)
        return function (node, attrib) { // use if available
            return node.hasAttribute(attrib);
        };
    return function (node, attrib) {
        var d = document.createElement('div'), // node for innerHTML
            e = node.cloneNode(false), // id attribute will be lost here
            i;
        if (attrib.toLowerCase() === 'id') return !!node.getAttribute('id');
        d.appendChild(e);
        i = d.innerHTML.length;                         // get original length
        e.setAttribute(attrib, e.getAttribute(attrib)); // set attrib to test
        return d.innerHTML.length === i;                // see if length changed
    };
}());
```